# Rails - How to force parameterized or downcase URLS when using find_by(object: params[:object]).id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I force parameterized or downcase URLS when using find_by id?

**articles controller**

```
    def index
        if params[:category].blank?
            @articles = Article.all.order("created_at DESC")
        else
            @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
            @articles = Article.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
        end
    end
```

**application view**

`link_to category.name, articles_path(category: category.name)`

**models:**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category
end


class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :articles
end
```

I've tried the following...

`link_to category.name, articles_path(category: category.name.downcase)`

`link_to category.name, articles_path(category: category.name).downcase`

but I'm receiving `undefined 'method 'id' for nil:NilClass`.

Only way I've been able to accomplish this was creating views for each category but I'm looking to keep this as dry as possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In which file did you get this error?

Comment: In the controller on this line: `@category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id`

Comment: How you are passing the `params[:category]`?

Comment: What is that you get in params[:category]?

Comment: the `params[:category]` is being passed by the `application view` template. `link_to category.name, articles_path(category: category.name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is an association between articles and category... You can get all the articles which belongs to Category:

```
@categories = Category.all
@categories.each do |category|
  @category ||= Category.find(category.id) if category.name.downcase == params[:name]
end
if @category
  @articles = @category.articles
else
  @articles = Article.all.order("created_at DESC")
end
```

Include the above code in the Articles Controller in index action.

in the view...

```
link_to category.name, articles_path(name: category.name.downcase)
```

Comment: I had to modify the index action from `if params[:category ].blank?` to `if params[:name].blank?` Now I am receiving `undefined method 'articles' for nil:NilClass` for `@articles = @category.articles`

Comment: add this in your view...link_to category.name, articles_path(name: category.name)

Comment: i've modified from from `articles_path(name: category.name.downcase)` to `articles_path(name: category.name)`, though this works, I don't have downcase urls.

Comment: I've installed this gem. Though the links are all downcased and no errors are returned, what's happening now is that no matter what `category` link I choose, it returns all of the articles as if each link called, `Article.all`.

Comment: please try the edited answer and remove the gem mentioned in the above comment......

Comment: Actually,,,, instead of the above method,  you can downcase all the category names before saving it to the database and while displaying it in view you can capitalize it. its very easy and simple

Comment: You're awesome!! Thank you! :). I was thinking about going with the `display_name` and `route_name` for category names in the db method if all else failed but this works perfectly. Again, thank you!